# My computer is only connecting to huge websites like FB and Google

Tags: wireless, 16.04, internet

I'm writing from a friend's computer in the same house. Even being just feet from the same wireless router, I can't access anything not owned by a super-massive corporation. My laptop's running Ubuntu 16.04, everything is up to date with relatively nice hardware, so I'm pretty baffled.

Comment: Are you sure those pages aren't cached, and you really actually have no internet?

Comment: Yes. I can connect with facebook just fine. But even using the terminal screen, it's acting like the only servers that exist are huge corporate ones. Then it's just fine

Comment: But I can still download software from the software center...

Comment: What happens when you ping different websites?

Comment: Lets be clear... you have TWO computers in the same house. One works fine on all Internet sites, and the other doesn't? Do you have DSL, cable modem, or something else? Cheers, Al

Comment: You likely have a DNS issue, where there DNS server given by your internet provider only connects you to well known hosts. Change your DNS server, either on the router or on your machine itself.

Comment: Oh god it's not letting me do anything about the DNS server. First I tried doing it through 'system settings' but my 'network menu' doesn't have an 'options' button like it's supposed to. So I tried using the terminal but sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf just brings up an empty screen. Every other computer's working great, but mine's only ok with mega-corporate sites, is this a sign that net-neutrality's gone out the window?

Answer (score 0):

It might not be your computer's problem (to do that you can check by using your computer to access not-controlled-by-mega-corporations-websites from some other internet access point) but rather a problem of your friend's router. S/he (or the one who set it up) might have allowed only certain popular websites and blocked all others in the router settings. Another possible case could be that the ISP might have done so - maybe on your friend's request. Just check about your computer first on some other internet access point.

Also, try using VPNs or proxy websites - who knows, some might just work.